# Change the leak time threshold in weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I am seeing this error in the logs but the JDBC connection never runs out (only have one), I wanted to increase the threshold to see if the exception goes away.

Exception:

[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '20' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']
2013-07-23 17:07:10.913 0       Error   Exception       java.lang.Throwable: Connection leak found: created statck

java.lang.Throwable: Connection leak found: created statck
        at glog.util.j2ee.jdbc.ASJTSConnection.(ASJTSConnection.java:23)
        at glog.util.j2ee.jdbc.ASConnectionEstablisher.connect(ASConnectionEstablisher.java:44)
        at glog.util.j2ee.jdbc.WLConnectionPoolInstance.reserve(WLConnectionPoolInstance.java:46)
        at glog.util.j2ee.jdbc.ASConnectionPoolInstance.reserve(ASConnectionPoolInstance.java:60)
        at glog.util.datasource.AppServerConnectionPool.reserve(AppServerConnectionPool.java:34)
        at glog.util.datasource.DataSource.reserve(DataSource.java:143)
        at glog.util.datasource.DataSource.reserve(DataSource.java:137)
        at glog.util.jdbc.noserver.T2SharedConnection$ReferencedConnection.addRef(T2SharedConnection.java:301)
        at glog.util.jdbc.noserver.T2SharedConnection$ReferencedConnection.addRef(T2SharedConnection.java:291)
        at glog.util.jdbc.noserver.T2SharedConnection.open(T2SharedConnection.java:57)
        at glog.server.query.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:30)
        at glog.server.query.JDBCFinder.openConnection(JDBCFinder.java:283)
        at glog.server.query.JDBCFinder.open(JDBCFinder.java:146)
        at glog.server.query.ListRetrieverBean.retrieve(ListRetrieverBean.java:39)
        at glog.server.query.ListRetrieverServerSideEJBWrapper.retrieve(ListRetrieverServerSideEJBWrapper.java:40)
        at glog.server.query.query_ListRetriever_whmeh3_EOImpl.retrieve(query_ListRetriever_whmeh3_EOImpl.java:58)
        at glog.server.query.query_ListRetriever_whmeh3_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)